# Help with difficult integral

Tags: calculus, integration

According to my textbook,

$$\int \left( 2 \cot^2{x} - 3 \tan^2{x} \right)dx = -2 \cot{x} - 3 \tan{x} + C$$

I am unable to arrive at this answer. Is this correct? If so, please help me with the integral.

Comment: Formule a pergunta em inglês.

Comment: have you tried differentiating the right hand side to check if its correct? It could be helpful to use the definitions of cot and tan and a substitution in terms of $\sin x$or $\cos x$ or an integration by parts. What did you try so far?

Comment: I tried using the trigonometric identity
$tan^2(x)=1-sec^2(x)$
And yes, I tried to differentiate, and could not get the answer, but what I really want is to learn, and thus verify

Comment: I got ... Thank you ... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a hint:
Use $$
\cot^2(x) = \csc^2(x) - 1\\
\frac{d}{dx} (-\cot(x)) = \csc^2(x).
$$
That is
$$
\int \csc^2(x) = -\cot(x) + C.
$$
Now [find something similar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Related_identities) to use for tangent.

Comment: Graças a ESSA Identidade $ COTG ^ 2 (x) = csc ^ 2 (x) -1 $ Consegui resolver, muito obrigado ...

Comment: @marcelolpjunior Se queres colocar a solução aqui, podes carregar abaixo em *answer your question*. Sugiro também que carregues no símbolo $\color{green} \checkmark$ à esquerda da resposta que mais te agradar.

Comment: @marcelolpjunior: lo siento, mi español es un poco oxidado.

Comment: @Thomas It's brazilian portuguese.

Comment: @GitGud: Sorry about getting that confused.

Comment: @Thomas Don't let it happen again, that's some serious stuff :P

Answer (score 3):

As John Carpenter said, you may use reduction formulae. Otherwise, you may try converting $ \tan^2 x $ to $\sec^2 x$ and $\cot^2x$ to $\csc^2 x$  which have 'direct' formulas.

Comment: I managed to solve ... Thank you ... :)

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Try using the reduction formulas if you have been taught them. If you haven't been taught them then tell me and I'll help you out.

Comment: Not have knowledge of these formulas, help me please, preferably with details.

Comment: Please refer to what Parth Thakkar and Thomas have added. They have given you half of the answer.

Comment: I got ... Thank you ... :)

Answer (score 1):

$\int (2\cot^2(x)-3\tan^2(x)) dx$=

$\int (2(\csc^2(x)-1)-3(\sec^2(x)-1)) dx$=

$\int (2\csc^2(x)-2-3\sec^2(x)+3) dx$=

$\int (2\csc^2(x)-3\sec^2(x)+1)dx$=
$ -2\cot(x)-3\tan(x)+x+C$